# Print single value from object on subscribe Angular 7

Tags: angular, api, angular7, subscribe

I'm new in angular 7
I need to print value inside properties read on subscribe api.

So my Init:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingVisible = false;
    this.getLogin().subscribe((result: User) => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    );
  }
```

My response API by Google Chrome console:

> {usrId: 1, usrUsername: "test", usrPassword: "test", usrEnable: true, usrLastLogin: null, …}
>   usrEnable: true
>   usrId: 1
>   usrLastLogin: null
>   usrLevel: 1
>   usrPassword: "test"
>   usrUsername: "test"
>   **proto**: Object

So i need to print like this:

```
this.getLogin().subscribe((result: User) => {
     console.log(result); //works, i see the data
     this.myUserReturn = result;
     console.log(result.UsrUsername); // undefined
     console.log(this.myUserReturn.UsrUsername); // undefined
     // why is all undefined !?
   }
);
```

I need to understand how to set my object by API.
Thanks.

Comment: Happening...since this is case sensitive ;)

Comment: omg...from server i've case sensitive and in the api response i've lost the first uppercase...i'm lost in water glass. thanks @AJT_82

Comment: No problem. Sometimes we all just need another set(s) of eyes :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it all working as a Subscribe should be set up but as mentioned the comment be careful for capitals as this will try to access values that dont exist. Code below should work.

```
this.getLogin().subscribe((result: User) => {
     console.log(result); //works, i see the data
     this.myUserReturn = result;
     console.log(result.usrUsername); 
     console.log(this.myUserReturn.usrUsername); 
   }
);
```

you are using a type here

```
((result: User) => {
```

Your IDE should be moaning that those values do not exist within the type, make sure you have not spilt the typing errors into here.

you could use something like so.

```
interface IUser {
usrUsername: string;
//rest of your values here typed case sensitive
}
```

Then change the type to below, this way you should always be informed when there are case sensitive problems or typo's. With a warning something like type 'UsrUsername' does not exist on IUser.

```
((result: IUser) => {
```